# How to change encoding bitrate adaptively to bandwidth during live rtmp publish using ffmpeg?

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg, rtmp, live-streaming, codec

I am currently using ffmpeg to read the recorded video by native frame rate and publish the stream to nginx rtmp server.

The command looks something like this

```
ffmpeg -re -i [video file] \
-vcodec libx264 -r 60 -g 120 -keyint_min 120 -vb [bitrate]\
-f flv -y rtmp://[server url];
```

I want to change the encoding bitrate of the software encoder manually,
according to the bandwidth fluctuation. For example,

```
If 2kbps< estimated_bandwidth <4kbps,  
     change ffmpeg bitrate to 3kbps, 1280x720 size
```

However, I couldn't find any framework or codec that supports dynamic bitrate change during encoding.

Is there a way that I could achieve this?
Last thing that I want to do is to implement the codec myself because I have no background.

Answer (score 1):

ffmpeg does not have this feature. x264, a common h264 encoder, and the default encoder in ffmpeg does have support for for changing the bitrate on the fly. You do not need to implement the coded yourself, but you do need to modify ffmpeg to add the feature.

Comment: Thank you for the answer ! Are there any documentation or sample implementation that I can refer to? How can I modify the ffmpeg and specifically what part should I lookup to add the feature?

Comment: yes, x264 has documentation. It's included in x264.h.